# Execute 2 JavaScript functions in order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function with two lines and I want them to be executed in order. The function is :

```
showNotification(message){
    $("#notificationMessageBody").html(message); // line1
    $("#notificationModal").modal('show');       //line2
}
```

So, whenever I call `showNotification("Hello World!")` how do I ensure `line1` is executed before `line2` (meaning content loading is done before the modal triggers)
Basically, I am trying to fill in my message in modal body and then show it, not before filling.

--EDIT--

The functions are indeed executing one after the other, but my modal pops before jQuery loads my `message` into my `#notificationMessageBody`

As a result, for example : If I call `showNotification("Hello")` I get a modal with "Hello" (the arrangement of modals and stuff is done), but then after that if I call `showNotification("World")` modal appears with "Hello" first then after that it changes to "World".

Note : "Hello" and "World" are big junk of text, so loading that into my DIV must be taking some time, I believe. Even though they are executed one after other, it appears (to common-er) that firstly modal is popping and then replacement is done. I hope the picture is a little clear now.

No AJAX involved anywhere here around the function. Basically, this is my custom alert() function one can say. A modal with proper ID is there in my page. I change the modal-body content(with jQuery's `.html()` function) and trigger the modal to show, as seen from the code.

Comment: Use `setTimeout`. `firstStatement; setTimeout(function() { secondStatment; }, 0);`

Comment: Those methods are synchronous so if it's not working correctly, you've misdiagnosed the problem. Does the modal not have the correct content when it opens?

Comment: Please provide demo showing them not executing in order. This sounds like an XY problem. Also show how you call this function. If it is related to an ajax request the problem likely lies with how you call it

Comment: Whenever I use `showNotification(msg)` function for the second time, the modal opens with whatever was in there before (the message with what I had used this function the first time) and then the content changes. Indeed they are executed one after other (almost same time), but I want the `.html()` to load the content into my DIV first and after that pop the modal.

Comment: There is no reason from what is shown that the second time would work differently. Again, this sounds like an ajax timing problem and there is not enough code shown for us to reproduce this. Create a demo that replicates problem

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`.promise()`](https://api.jquery.com/promise/) method (added in jQuery 1.6) to ensure the second one is executed after first is completed:

```
$("#notificationMessageBody").html(message).promise().done(function() {
    $("#notificationModal").modal('show');  
});
```

Comment: uhm...  well, this is a pretty poor usage of `.promise`. for one, it isn't needed, because `.html` is synchronous and therefore calling one after the other is enough to ensure they run one after the other, and two, it's misleading... because `.promise().done()` isn't waiting for `.html()` to be done, it's waiting for any existing animations to finish. This is just a glorified `setTimeout(fn, 0)`. All it's really doing is pushing the modal show to the callback queue immediately.